# Regex matching /xx/xx/ or /xx/xx - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regular exression which will match the string `/xx/xx/` as well as `/xx/xx`. xx can be any two letters.

Comment: What have you tried? You only have to match a slash, 2 characters, a slash, 2 characters, and a optional slash...

Comment: `/\/[a-z][a-z]\/[a-z][a-z]\/?/i`

Comment: Here, you can test what you've tried so far : http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpelest solution would be a literal pattern of "slash, 2 chars, slash, 2 chars, optional slash":

```
/\/\w\w\/\w\w\/?/
```

Structure:

```
/   //JS's "Start regex"
\/  // Escaped "Slash" (matches / )
\w  // Any word character ([A-Za-z0-9_]) (Twice)
    // Then a slash and 2 \w's
\/? // Optional slash.
```

Usage:

```
"/xx/xx/".match(/\/\w\w\/\w\w\/?/) // ["/xx/xx/"]
"/xx/xx".match(/\/\w\w\/\w\w\/?/) // ["/xx/xx"]
"/xx/x".match(/\/\w\w\/\w\w\/?/) // null
```

You could make the regex a *little* shorter:

```
/(\/\w\w){2}\/?/
```

Also, you may want to replace `\w` with `[A-z]`, since `\w` also matches digits (`[0-9]`) and the underscore character (`_`). If you want the regex to only allow letters, use `[A-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below would help:

```
\/[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z]\/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z](\/)?/
```

Assuming x could be caps or small letters.

Test Samples:

```
Ab/cd  --> True
AA/BB  --> True
A/B    --> False
XX/SS/ --> True
/X/x/  --> False
```